# Odoo 10: How to insert value to a many2one field in table with create method?

Tags: python, relational-database, odoo, oncreate

my many2one field in models.py :

```
commercial_group = fields.Many2one("simcard.simcard")
```

I want to add a new value in this many2one field using create method. That value I am getting from an SOAP response which i am parsing using element tree:

```
response=requests.post(self.url,cert=self.cert,data=body,headers=self.headers) 
 element = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
 body_el = element.find('{schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope}Body') 
 commercial_group=body_el.find('{example.com}commercialGroup')
```

And I want to create a new record with this commercialGroup field and some other fields :

```
record.sudo().create({
                                     "icc": icc.text,
                                     "imsi": imsi.text,
                                     "msisdn": msisdn.text,
                                     "lte_status": lte_status.text,
                                     "life_cycle_status": life_cycle_status.text,
                                     "sim_model": simmodel.text,
                                     "gprs_status": gprsStatus.text,

                                     "consumption_monthly_data_limit": consumption_monthly_data_limit.text,
                                     "consumption_monthly_data_value": consumption_monthly_data_value.text,
                                     "consumption_monthly_data_thrReached": consumption_monthly_data_thrReached.text,

                                     "commercial_group": commercial_group.text,

                                     "country": country.text,
                                     "operator": operator.text

                                       })
              http.request.env.cr.commit()
```

and i get this error :

```
INFO test odoo.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "simcard_simcard" ("id", "consumption_monthly_data_limit", "consumption_monthly_data_thrReached", "msisdn", "country", "lte_status", "consumption_monthly_data_value", "life_cycle_status", "icc", "gprs_status", "sim_model", "operator", "commercial_group", "imsi", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('simcard_simcard_id_seq'), '0', '0', '34590169', 'CH', 'false', '0', 'ACTIVE', '89293165951', '2', 'M2M Plug-in', 're', '1GB_dynPool_Plus_LTE', '29782', 1, 1, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id
2018-09-19 13:44:27,441 5714 ERROR test odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 642, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 684, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 334, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 327, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 942, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 507, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 895, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/simcard/models/models.py", line 259, in sync
    parse.parseXml(subscriptionDatas)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/addons/simcard/models/parse.py", line 71, in parseXml
    "operator": operator.text
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 3846, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 3941, in _create
    cr.execute(query, tuple(u[2] for u in updates if len(u) > 2))
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/sql_db.py", line 231, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "1GB_dynPool_Plus_LTE"

                                                             ^
```

What is the right way to insert value to a many2one field in table with create method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is fine. You values dictionary has a value for an integer field, which obviously gets a non integer value (`1GB_dynPool_Plus_LTE`). So you either have the wrong value for this field or your field definition is wrong or you have to parse your value to an integer for example through a mapping.

Edit:

Your field `commercial_group` is a many2one relation to model `simcard.simcard`. I don't know the definition for that model so i will assume the following:

```py
class Simcard(models.Model):
    _name = "simcard.simcard"

    name = fields.Char()
```

Now on creation Odoo needs IDs or nothing for many2one fields. So either you search for an existing record for that model or create one or just let it empty. My following example uses a mix. First i will search, and if nothing found, my code example will create a `simcard.simcard` record and uses it later.

```py
commercial_group_name = commercial_group.text
simcard = record.env['simcard.simcard'].search(
    [('name', '=', commercial_group_name)], limit=1)
if not simcard:
    simcard = record.env['simcard.simcard'].create(
        {'name': commercial_group_name})
record.sudo().create({
    # other values
    "commercial_group": simcard.id,
    # other values
})
```

Comment: one thing i am sure that i dont have wrong value. 1GB_dynPool_Plus_LTE has to go in commercial_group. What would be the right field definition for my field when i want to see a drop down menu in GUI? And to which integer i should map my value?Sorry i am new in odoo.

Comment: Could you please add your field definitions into your question?

Comment: Oh wait, you already have it for this field. It's a many2one. I will edit my answer.

Comment: But i need the model definition for model `simcard.simcard`, because you have to search the record if you only get a `text` by SOAP.

Comment: What do u mean by model definition? And one more information, i dont know which values will be comimg from SOAP call , so i wont know which value should be mapped to which integer.

Comment: Your field commercial_group is a relational field to relation `simcard.simcard`. For such fields you have either give Odoo an ID of a record of that model/relation or nothing or you have to create a new record. I will edit it into my answer.

Comment: my model definition : 
class simcard(models.Model):
     _name = 'simcard.simcard'
     __instance = None
     _lastUsedModelId = 0
    commercial_group = fields.Many2one("simcard.simcard")
  .......some other fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180532/discussion-between-anubhav-jhalani-and-czoellner).